# How to retrieve files changed in range of revisions in Subversion?

Tags: svn

How would I retrieve all files from the repository, along with the folder structure, changed in a range of revisions, say from 1000-1920?

Comment: Do you want the actual files, or just a list of their paths? What do you mean by "changed"? Does deletion count? How about property changes? What about a file that was deleted in r1001 but restored (as it was in r1000) in r1920. Is that a change?

Comment: I need the actual files, that are included in that revision. By change I just meant the files listed in that revision. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 22):

If you just want the list of changed paths, have a look at the --summarize option on diff.

```
svn diff --summarize -r1000:1920 https://my.org/myrepo/
```

Answer (score 12):

That depends a little on what you intend to do with the data. If you're only interested in inspecting the data manually, you can do

```
svn log -r1000:1920 -q -v | grep "   M" | sort -u
```

to see all modified files, for example.

If you want to do something more programmatically, you can pass the --xml flag to svn log and get all the log data as XML output:

```
svn log -r1000:1920 --xml > log1000-1920.xml
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this helps, but if you're using Windows, and you have TortoiseSVN installed. It has this functionality. Check *[Using TortoiseSVN to Export Only New/Modified Files](http://verysimple.com/2007/09/06/using-tortoisesvn-to-export-only-newmodified-files/)* for the details. Again, this is assuming you're using Windows.

Comment: I get a permission error when I try to follow this link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will give you a tree containing only those files that exist in r1920 and were changed or added between r1000 and r1920. It's a bash script, so you'll need Linux and the GNU tools or something comparable.

```
 #!/bin/bash

repo=https://zsvn.brz.gv.at/svn/ju-vj/trunk/vj
lo=1000
hi=1920
wc=changed_files$hi

# all files as of revision $hi
svn export $repo@$hi $wc

(# files that have changed
 svn diff --summarize -r$lo:$hi $repo \
    | egrep -e "^[AM]" \
    | cut -c7- \
    | sed -e "s,$repo,," \
    | sed -e "s, /,," \
     | while read p
 do # omit directories, emit only files
     if [[ -f $wc/$p ]]
     then
         echo "$p"
     fi
 done
 # all files (omit directories)
 svn ls -R $repo@$hi | egrep -v -e "/$"
) \
| sort | uniq -u \
| (cd $wc ; xargs rm)

# The last lines select only those files which are unique when the two
# lists are combined, that is all those files that are in revision $hi
# and have not changed.  These are then fed to rm by xargs to remove
# them.

# what's left is an export containing only those files that changed or
# were added between revisions $lo and $hi.
```