# Subversion: Get all files from a revision

Tags: svn, export, revision

How do I export/get all the files belonging to a revision?

For example:
On revision 5434 if we have commited 5 files, how do I get all the 5 files on the specified revision?

Something like `svn export` with revision number, but I **only** want the files that I commited on that revision.

**Edit:**

Duplicate of "[Subversion: Check out only those files affected during a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971188/subversion-check-out-only-those-files-affected-during-a-specific-commit)".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971188/subversion-check-out-only-those-files-affected-during-a-specific-commit

Comment: Yep, same question. Guess this can be closed.

Comment: This question is a specific variant of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427781/subversion-how-to-retrieve-files-changed-in-range-of-revisions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up with writing a small PHP script to get the files and export them.

I got the file list with the command

```
svn log /home/raja/coderepo/ -qv -r12423 | awk '/\//{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

By e.g:

```
svn diff -r 1048:1049 --summarize
```