# SVN: How to checkout all the files that have been committed since yesterday?

Tags: svn, shell, version-control, tortoisesvn, build-automation

My project is in .net. For build automation I need to checkout all the project folders in which any commit has happened since yesterday.Now this data needs to be fetched on a daily basis through a batch file in windows.Need help!!!

```
     svn log -r{2012-1-21}:{2012-1-24} > report.txt
```

I was using the above command to get the data for single day manually.Now it has to be fetched everyday and the folder needs to be checked out to local drive too.

Comment: Windows is this case is bad... Well, why you reject `svn up` method of getting sources? svn log with date-range will give you big headache - just read [Is Subversion a Day Early?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) note from SVN-Book

Comment: Also read [Subversion: How to retrieve files changed in range of revisions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427781/subversion-how-to-retrieve-files-changed-in-range-of-revisions)

Answer (score 0):

Use following command:

```
svn update -r {YYYY-MM-DD}
```

for example:

```
svn update -r {2012-02-20}
```